# How to iterate through all properties (sub/child properties included) of an object in a PCL project?

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I want to create a method which would accept "any type which inherits from the Object data type" (generic) as a parameter and then iterate over all it's properties.

I tried this:

```
foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj, null));
}
```

But the `GetProperties()` method doesn't exist in a PCL project.

Answer (score 3):

In most PCL profiles, at least the .NET 4.5 based ones, you should use `TypeInfo` instead of `Type` to get type information.

Basically you can replace `obj.GetType().GetProperties()` with

```
obj.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetProperties()
```

For a list of all properties declared for the specific type, use `DeclaredProperties` instead of `GetProperties()`. For the complete list of properties, including  inherited, non-public, instance, and static properties, you could use the extension method `GetRuntimeProperties()`.

For more info on `TypeInfo` see the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. This works. I edited my question a bit, it wasn't clear enough before or you just overlooked that i need to iterate through all properties even the sub/child ones. I think that it would be easiest with recursion. But i don't know how to check if the current object is int or List or user custom object. This way i would know then if i need to go deeper into the object or not.

Comment: I would say that it is still not clear from the question or the example that this is what you want to do. I recommend that you ask for that answer in a separate question.